# How can I limit a ldap query to just a few OUs ? LDAP bind to a domain user account

Tags: ldap

For LDAP queries I created a special account (domain user) located in :
OU=work, CN=do, CN=apropos, CN=tev
How can I restrict the read permission of this account to just:
OU=trouble, OU=now, CN=do, CN=apropos, CN=tev

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy as it seems, because the default permissions grant read access on all OUs to all authenticated users, regardless of group membership; in order to achieve what you want, you need to either modify the default permissions (with possible heavy impact on various applications), or use explicit deny ACEs for your restricted users.

See here for more info: http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/hiding-data-active-directory.